# Inline lambda - get rate with latest date

Tags: c#-4.0, date, lambda, group-by

The MVC ViewPage contains Users (intranet.Model.User).  Each user may have one or more rates of pay represented in the model as intranet.model.User.UserRates.

I need to be able to display the latest rate of pay per user using an inline Lambda expression but I am having no success (an error message is displayed rather than the rate of pay).

My latest incarnation is:

```
     
        <% var latestRate = item.UserRates
                               .GroupBy(hr=>hr.rate)
                               .Select(g=>g.Single(
                                  d=>d.effective == g.Max(m=>m.effective))
                                ); %>
```

`<%= Html.Encode(latestRate) %>
  </td>`

Error message in column is:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Decimal,intranet.Models.UserRate],intranet.Models.UserRate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final iteration (for now):

```
  <% var userRate = item.UserRates
                        .OrderByDescending(hr=>hr.effective)
                        .FirstOrDefault() ?? new intranet.Models.UserRate(); %>

  <td class="hrlyRate">                                         
      <%= Html.Encode(string.Format("{0:0.000}", userRate.rate))%>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out exactly what your data looks like, but couldn't you do something like this?

```
var latestRate = item.UserRates
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.effective)
                     .First();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I had that in one of my iterations but face the issue of some users not having any user rates and so the code throws a "Sequence contains no elements" error.  I could ensure, in the DB, that at least each user has a default 0.00 user rate, but I would like to think that I could mitigate this issue in the lambda too.

Comment: Working on .FirstOrDefault() rather than first.  this still gives me a null object in certain cases but I am currently working on trapping that

Comment: <td class="hrlyRate">
   <% var latestRate = item.UserRates
                           .OrderByDescending(hr=>hr.effective)
                           .FirstOrDefault() ?? new intranet.Models.UserRate(); %>

   <%= Html.Encode(latestRate.rate)%>
</td>